# Actionscript 3 detect successive key press

Tags: actionscript-3

I have 2 movie clips. One has a character walking and the other one he's running. How do I make it so that if I press the left arrow key, it will play the walking clip. If I press the left arrow in quick succession, it will switch to the running clip. I am using Actionscript 3.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Wouldn't a key down for a certain period of time to break into a spring be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires a bit of codework as Flash AS3 does not have native support for double clicks. Here is a simple example of how you can achieve this effect with SetTimeout

```
var keyCodeToListenFor = '13';  // can be any keycode;
var keySinglePress:Boolean = false;
var keyDoublePress:Boolean = false;
var timeToWaitForDoublePress:Number = 400;
var waitingForDoublePress:Boolean = false;
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, handleKeyDown);


function handleKeyDown(e:Event) {

   if (e.keyCode == keyCodeToListenFor) {

       keySinglePress = true;
       if (waitingForDoublePress) {
           keyDoublePress = true;
       }

       waitingForDoublePress = true;

       setTimeout(function() { 
           waitingForDoublePress = false; 
           keyDoublePress = false;
       }, timeToWaitForDoublePress);


   }

   if (keyDoublePress) {
       trace('You logged a double press!')
   } else if (keySinglePress)   {
       trace('You logged a single press!');
   }
}
```

Comment: I think the function that's called via `setTimeout()` should check if double press was already initiated, if so, it should return. Say you want your player char to run for long, you tap D twice (for running right), it starts running, then BAM timer kicks in and the char stops running and starts walking.

Comment: Yes excellent point. The above example should be used as a loose guideline at best.